# doctor schedulering design SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to run this line of code to create a database to schedule doctor.

```
EmployeeID int primary key not null,
DPhone int not null,
DFirstName nvarchar (20) not null,
DLastName nvarchar (25) not null,
Specialization nvarchar (100) not null,
Cost int not null);

create table schedule(
DEmployeeID int not null, foreign key (DEmployeeID) references doctor (EmployeeID),
SDay nvarchar (9) not null,
SDate date not null,
STime time not null,
BookingStatus char not null,
primary key (DEmployeeID, SDate, STime),
PMedicalID int, foreign key (PMedicalID) references patient (MedicalID));



create table medRecords (
prescription nvarchar (100),
diagnosis nvarchar (100) not null,
Pdescription text not null,
medRecID int not null primary key,
MedicalID int, foreign key (MedicalID) references patient (MedicalID),
SDate date not null, foreign key (SDate) references schedule (SDate),
EmployeeID int not null, foreign key (EmployeeID) references doctor (EmployeeID))
```

This is the error

There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Schedule' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__MedRecord__SDate__3D5E1FD2'.

The Sdate is already a primary key so i don't understand why i get this error.

edit
I already have a patiens table created

Comment: The column/expression which you refer to must be indexed or to be an index prefix. For example, when you write `references schedule (SDate)` then there must exist an index by `(SDate)` (strict matching) or by some `(SDate, other columns)` in the table `schedule `. *The Sdate is already a primary key* The PK expression is `(DEmployeeID, SDate, STime)`, it is not useful for your FK until `SDate` is placed first.

Comment: You lost create table from first table and there is no patient table(maybe) and it's better if you name your FKs so the error becomes clearer.

Comment: SDate is NOT the primary key of schedule - it is one of the three columns in the PK. You CANNOT create a foreign key to only part of a primary key. Your FK in medRecords must be associated with all three columns of the primary key in schedule.